# Handle addition of new element with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-events

A page has a list of articles. Clicking "more" button, more articles will be loaded via AJAX

I need to make newly added articles appearing smoothly.

I can do it with `jQuery.fadeIn()` method.

The problem is - how to handle such event, when new elements was added to jQuery element in question.

I don't want to call custom JavaScript method at server. Server side must be weak about any styling features.

So, the code must be clean at server side - it must just add new elements, using `jQuery.append()` method.

At the client side, it should be like this:

```
$("#articles").elementAdded(function(newElem){
   newElem.hide();
   newElem.fadeIn(600);
});
```

`elementAdded` is a kind of method, I'm looking for.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is about an `elementAdded` event, which would be better termed a `dommodified` event, IMO.  These don't exist in Javascript, although I think jQuery should mimic them.   This is not hard to do in theory:

```
(function($, undefined) {
    var _append = $.fn.append;

    $.fn.append = function(newHtml) {
        return this.each(function(i, el){
            var $el = $(el);
            _append.call($el, newHtml);
            $el.trigger('contentappended');
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

You could then capture modifications with `append()` by binding to the `contentappended` event:

```
$('#articles').bind('contentappended', function() {
    $(this).hide().fadeIn(600);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The server doesn't call append, all javascript is executed on the client. Just call jQuery.fadeIn() at the point where you add the new elements.

Comment: Yes, you are right.I mean, that js code (adding articles), that will be supmitted via XHR, i write in server-files. And i should avoid it.